# Need some important hints :- Sql injection for different queries..

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp-1.3

How to prevent my code and sql architecture from sql injection..??

I am using Php for coding..

I have some form for login. I read some sql injection queries

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE smth='" + UserInput + "'";
ExecuteSql(sql);

SELECT fieldlist
  FROM table
 WHERE field = 'steve@unixwiz.net'';
```

I know sql injection is occurred because of our bad coding and bad queries for retrieving data from database.. i did some google for safing my project from sql injector but i didn't got some proper information..

I used cakephp framework also for coding and i got knowledge that in cakephp sql injection is very tough because it sanitize the  queries.. is it true??

I got this information for that :--

```
CakePHP already protects you against SQL Injection if you use CakePHP's ORM methods (such as find() and save()) and proper array notation (ie. array('field' => $value)) instead of raw SQL. For sanitization against XSS its generally better to save raw HTML in database without modification and sanitize at the time of output/display.
```

will anybody guide me for that??

thanks !!

Comment: Using CakePHP and making queries like `smth='" + UserInput + "'"` is like buying safe and using combination 0-0-0-0

Comment: I'm not gonna guide you through the basics, they are well documented. You may want to start reading a [basic CakePHP tutorial for beginners](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/326/The-Cake-Blog-Tutorial)

Comment: @Uriel_SVK yes you are correct , but if i want to retrive like smth='.$data['name'].' ; is this correct way to pass..

Comment: @Kaii thanks for your link, but i want to prevent my project if i am using PHP without framwork..

Comment: @Learner you should then explicitly mention that in your question.

Comment: not a pro in cakephp but should not be [DataSource](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/data-source#method-DataSourceread) class used for db manipulation? And if you want something safe for php without frameworks check [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Learner is talking specifically about queries in the CakePHP framework, not general injection (although that's important to know about too.

When CakePHP says

> CakePHP already protects you against SQL Injection if you use CakePHP's ORM methods (such as find() and save()) and proper array notation (ie. array('field' => $value)) instead of raw SQL. For sanitization against XSS its generally better to save raw HTML in database without modification and sanitize at the time of output/display.

What you need to do is what it says. It DOES NOT protect you when you're running arbitrary queries against the database - it can't, because you're bypassing CakePHP.  When it does protect you is queries running through the framework:

```
$result = $this->Article->find(
    'first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Article.id' => $articleIDtoFind)));
```

In this example, it doesn't matter where `$articleIDtoFind` comes from, the query is safe. (It might just not work if it's full of junk)

Comment: it means cakephp is initially safe from injection.. u want to say something like that???

Comment: It's safe from injection as long as you use the CakePHP methods for dealing with data. If you have a page that happens to be using the CakePHP framework, but use your own hand-written SQL strings and executed directly through the mysql* methods, then of course CakePHP can't protect you.

Answer (score 2):

Any input should be properly sanitized to prevent injection:

```
$UserInput = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['inputfield']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE smth='". $UserInput ."'";
ExecuteSql(sql);
```

You can always sanitize your inputs. If you have some actual code it would help to see. Just apply the function "mysql_real_escape_string" to any strings before adding it to the query.

UPDATE:

I'm not positive I read this from your comment correctly, but this is how your code should look:

```
<?php 
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";
echo $query;
if($result = mysql_query($query)) {
    // matching user + password found
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    print_r($row); //This will show you the results of the query.
}
else {
    // no matching user and password -- login not granted
    echo "you fail.";
}
?>
```

Since I added the "mysql_real_escape_string" function, characters like ' and " will be escaped so that the database does not treat them as parts of the query.

Comment: <?php
// We didn't check $_POST['password'], it could be anything the user wanted! For example:
$_POST['username'] = 'aidan';
$_POST['password'] = "' OR ''='";

// Query database to check if there are any matching users
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='{$_POST['username']}' AND password='{$_POST['password']}'";
mysql_query($query);

// This means the query sent to MySQL would be:
echo $query;
?>  // how to prevent from this type of sql injection

Comment: Please see my update regarding this. In the future, post code as an edit to your question so it's easier to read :)

Comment: What does this have to do with CakePHP though? Completely bypassing the framework is not a helpful answer.

Comment: It's helpful because it doesn't matter what he's using, it was purely a demonstration of how to use mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible sql injection method is to enter a data with different conditions.
Eg: Your aboue query can hack with entering  the following string.

```
 a' or '1=1
```

To avoid this injection you can use the following methods
1.mysql_real_escape_string();
   eg: before executing the query

use,
     $user_data=mysql_real_escape_string($user_data);
2. addslashes()

```
eg : $user_data=addslashes($user_data)
```

Answer (score -1):

No method is 100% fullproof, IMHO. However, sanitizing inputs as well as handling form data correctly (which is where 99% of attacks will come from, that textbox that you forgot to watch out for) will cut down on the occurrences.

When it comes to putting data into the database, most people sanitize the strings, looking for characters to escape. There is a joke, on the internet, about "Little Bobby; DROP TABLES;" which makes light of this problem. My personal method is to base64 encode the strings going into the database, and base64 decode them as they leave it. Why not use the built-ins? You can, and probably should. However, in my case, I've performed a lot of work using dissimilar databases / file formats, and base64 is useful when dealing with any of them.

As for forms, which is part of the fun when dealing with potential attackers, you would want to use POST / SESSION as much as possible. Why? Because in general, you want to give attackers as little information about the internals of your website / database as is reasonably possible. Imagine a page, which took a Get request, which executed the parameters taken from it directly: "accounts.php?ACCOUNTID=2347289". A lazy programmer will have a field, in a table, that matches that variable, character for character. However, as many people have pointed out, this part does not strictly deal with SQL-Injection attacks, but I felt was worth bringing up since you appear new to all of this.

Comment: I read some attacking method "Brute-force password guessing" and etc.. if i was using simple PHP then it will work..

Comment: Indeed. If you are authenticating users, you should store a hashed / salted version of their passwords (never the originals), and verify against that. Additionally, it may be in your interests to assign a user id token, rather than pass around the username / password from page to page.

Comment: You can as well have a garbaged POST as well as a GET, and an attacker could as well add ' and " characters to a string and then base64 it. What you describe has nothing to do with SQL injection avoiding.

Comment: @glglgl we can not salt or hashed our data or encrypt  to prevent from sql injection?/

Comment: @Learner salting and hashing has nothing to do with sql injection, sqli is about user input sanitizing. Of course if you are storing your passwords as text then you deserve to be hacked, really, ask Sony

Comment: @glglgl for preventing we have to store our password as encrypt from md5 or baseencode not as simple text/.. got it..

Comment: @Learner NEVER USE MD5 FOR PASSWORDS!!!! It has been broken!!! Use sha256 or sha512 with some good salt

Comment: @edze great:--  saltedhash(password) = hash(password+salt)
Or
saltedhash(password) = hash(hash(password)+salt)

Comment: @Learner also, [Base64-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is NOT a counter-measure to plaintext passwords. in fact, it is just another *representation* (encoding) for plaintext which can be easily decoded. In Base64 there is no encryption involved.

Comment: Guys, to clear things up, I wasn't suggesting using base64 for usernames / passwords. Just for string data in general.